# How to get node's port that is registered on hub

Tags: selenium-grid

I setup a hub with (java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub) on a machine A.
I used many machines to setup multiple nodes with random port to hub.

```
 (
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role node  -hub http:///[hub ip]:4444//grid//register [Random port number])
```

I know that I can see the node information (node's IP and port) that is registered on "

```
http:///[hub ip]:4444//grid//console"..
How can i get node's IP and port without open page "http:////[hub ip]:4444//grid//console"?.
```

Are there any API support to get node's ip or port?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Selenium Grid Servlet to obtain this information - however this will run within the Selenium Grid process. Good example to set up a servlet can be found at this sample:
[How do you create a /postResults servlet for selenium core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748958/how-do-you-create-a-postresults-servlet-for-selenium-core)

However, I get the sense that you want to expose this information to a third process. In this case, I would recommend 1) writing a servlet which exposes this data as json, 2) your process should make a web request to the servlet on the hub and parse the json response.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But i'm not familiar with servlet. Could you tell me more details?